# Yii2 click event after search/filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

I have this code in `Jquery` where I capture the click on any row of a `GridView` index and redirect to another page.

```
 $('tbody > tr').click(function(){

     pId= this.id;

     window.location.href = urllink + '&pId=' + pId;

});
```

The code works well but only if I do not use the search/filter in the index.

After doing a search on any column in the index, the click doesn't respond. Why does that happen? How can I solve it?

Comment: does your grid use pjax?

Comment: Any error messages in the console?

Comment: Yes it's using pjax. And there are no messages in the console.

Comment: The event is not registered on the (new) table row. Try delegating the click $(document).click('tbody > tr',function() {

} );

Comment: I just check that it's working fine after search if I remove pjax. But there is a way to make it work with pjax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`EVENT DELEGATION`**](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for this purpose. You can target the parent div for the grid view which could be `pjax` too if you are using then you can assign an id to `pjax` container like

```
<?php Pjax(['id'=>'my-container'])?>
```

and then use the following

```
 $(document).on('click','#my-container > table > tbody > tr',function(){

     pId= this.id;

     window.location.href = urllink + '&pId=' + pId;

});
```

or you can use `pjax:success` event too that fires after replacing `HTML` content loaded from the server, for doing the same thing above see [**`DOCS`**](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events)

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
    $('#my-container > table > tbody > tr').on('click',function(){
         pId= this.id;

         window.location.href = urllink + '&pId=' + pId;
    });

});
```

*EDIT: You might need to adjust the element path `'#my-container > table > tbody > tr'` according to your `HTML` you might have to remove `>` from `#my-container > table` if the table is not the first child*

Comment: Thanks for your answer Muhammad. It work for me without '#my-container'. This is the line: 
$(document).on('click', 'tbody > tr', function(){

Comment: glad it worked for you do mark the answer as correct if it helped you out. @MarkWatney